# How do I add a value to a ComboBox selection in C#?

Tags: c#, combobox, label, box

So I have two combo boxes, one being dependant on another. I also have a label  which I want the price to be displayed in. 
 I would like to assistance on adding a  number value to the ComboBox selection, which would then showUp on my Label.

```
 if (CarModelCB.Text == "Gallardo")
 { 
     lblCarPrice.Text = "180000";
 }
```

I'm getting quite a few red lines but this is roughly how I want it to be like.

Comment: Could you share a bit of actual code? Also, what UI engine are you using? WinForms? WPF?

Comment: It's a WFA and that was the code I was attempting to write. I'm quite new to this but I was trying to sort out a car dealership where one CB would show brands, the other show models of the brand. Then the code written on the top was to indicate what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a Dictionary, which stores the prices and uses the CarModel names as the keys.

```
Dictionary<string, int> prices = new Dictionary<string, int>();

prices.Add("Gallardo", 180000);
```

Then you can simply check for the price in the SelectedIndexChanged event of the ComboBox

```
private void CarModelCB_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        lblCarPrice.Text = prices[CarModelCB.Text].ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would the dictionary be declared under the Form class?

Answer (score 0):

I would use simple Databinding...
First you will need a Model like this ...

```
class Car
{
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

Beware: You should probably implement INotifyPropertyChanged. There are a lot of examples on the internet.

Then bind the comboboxes to the model and set the relevant Datamember.